# Subtract two column values and store result in another column

Tags: sql

I have the one table eg tbl_1 and i have column eg A B C. When I insert into column A and B its result store into C like c=a-b.

Comment: Does your RDBMS support triggers?

Comment: You could just define Column C as A - B

Comment: The RDBMS that you are using will greatly drive the answers you receive. As a generic solution, you could do `insert into tbl_1 (A, B, C) SELECT val_A, val_B, val_A - val_B` (SQL Server syntax); however, if your RDBMS supports calculated columns, @Siyual has the best suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to create virtual/computed columns while creating a table structure, Since you dint specified which RDBMS you are using, please following links (the one that suits you) :
Hope it helps you.

[MYSQL](http://mysqlserverteam.com/generated-columns-in-mysql-5-7-5/)

[ORACLE 11G](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/virtual-columns-11gr1)

[SQL SERVER](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/07/27/sql-server-computed-column-persisted-and-storage/)

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_1 
(
    A int,
    B int,
    C AS A - B
);
```

Comment: Not sure why this is down-voted.

Comment: @AWinkle Me neither, thanks!

Comment: @AWinkle Probably because [Tim has again lost his keys](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215379/should-drive-by-downvoting-be-more-effectively-caught/215397#215397)